# how to find the redirection page, when redirecting with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

We are building an analytics sdk and it tracks what is clicked and after that click which page it is redirected to, we do not encounter any problem on finding hard coded href, but some websites make the redirection with `window.location.replace`

Example,

```
$("button").click(function() {
   window.location.replace("dummy_website");
});
```

how can I intercept the redirection and than let go of the redirection ?

**by the way I want to track only in website redirections, I do not want to track redirection to other website**